# when I run nuxt porject, have app crash error

Tags: nuxt.js

My computer was reinstalled at yesterday.I try re-run the nuxt project.But have error.

nvm versiong:1.1.7

node version:10.12.0

npm version:6.4.1

nuxt version:2.0.0

package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development nodemon server/index.js --watch server",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node server/index.js",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.vue --ignore-path .gitignore ."
  },
```

when I run `npm run dev`,Have this message

```
[nodemon] 1.19.2
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching dir(s): server\**\*
[nodemon] starting `node server/index.js`
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

when I run `npm run build`,Have this message

```
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 3221225477
npm ERR! blog@1.0.0 build: `nuxt build`
npm ERR! Exit status 3221225477
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the blog@1.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Excuse me, what is this question.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I disable nvm, and install node, the porject can run